# Implementing SSL certificate in asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https, certificate

I have created a .pfx file in order to certify the site.But in our website we are using links to two sites managed by third party which is not HTTPS.If this is the case and if i do certification in our website will it be effective.As a trial  i have implemented pfx file in IIS, when the client machine accessed site first it will prompt with usual dialogue, and after forcefully moving in to the site, if you install it in local store, and if you clik "show all content" on the bottom of the IE, we can see all the data with HTTPS link.But no padlock in the left side of the browser, why i am not getting the padlock? if you dont have padlock and if the site is HTTPS doe that good? is there any better implementation for this scenario.One more question is if we have an HTTPS site which contain HTTP  sites from third party deployed in different server, does that work properly with SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to create an SSL certificate for an asp.net website is well explained in this tutorial, check,

[ssl integration tips](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx)